# delete button event on listview doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity with a listview, the listview contains an imageview as a delete button in each row. I have added onclicklistener to the imageview but it doesn't work.

**This is the main Layout which contains the ListView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cart_list_view"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent">
</ListView>
```

**this is the layout handled by the Arraylist Adapter:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_cart"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.badr.eco.CartActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="row"
        android:id="@+id/ImgProduct"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleProduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180px"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PriceProduct"
        android:layout_below="@id/TitleProduct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete_item_from_cart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/PriceProduct"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**code of my Arraylist adapter :**

```
public class CartListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ImageView img_prdtct;
    private TextView title_prdct;
    private TextView  price_prdct;
    private DBHelper Mydb;
    private ImageView Img_delete;

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> My_prdcts_List;

    public CartListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String>    objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        My_prdcts_List = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
              getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, parent, false);

        String obj = My_prdcts_List.get(position);
        String [] items = obj.split("/");

        img_prdtct  = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ImgProduct);
        title_prdct = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.TitleProduct);
        price_prdct = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.PriceProduct);
        Img_delete  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_item_from_cart);

        title_prdct.setText(items[0]);
        price_prdct.setText(items[1] + "DH");
        img_prdtct.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(items[2]));

        //Les evenements
        img_prdtct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Log.d("Clicked", "deleteButton");
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**Acivity Code :**

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DBHelper Mydb;
    private ArrayList<String> Array_List;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_main);

        Array_List = new ArrayList<>();
        Mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        Array_List = Mydb.getAllRows("cart");

        CartListAdapter adapter = new CartListAdapter(this,0,Array_List);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cart_list_view);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And finally this the result, but the event click doesn't work. 
[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVDEs.png)

Comment: where are your setTag ?

Comment: i found the mistake, i have just replaced the img_prdtct.setOnClickListener to Img_delete.setOnClickListener

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I would recommend you to delete your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i found the mistake, i have just replaced the 
 **img_prdtct.setOnClickListener** to  **Img_delete.setOnClickListener**